# Finding accumulation points of a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am given the set $$E=\left\{\frac{n^{(-1)^{n}}}{n+1} \colon n\in\mathbb{N} \right\}$$ and asked to find all accumulation points (and prove so). I can prove that 0 and 1 are accumulation points and that for any real number $a$ where $$a<0 \qquad\text{or}\qquad a>1$$ that $a$ is not an accumulation point. However I'm having difficulty showing that there is no $$a \in (0,1)$$ that is an accumulation point.

I might be able to show that no member of E itself is an accumulation point by induction but that seems awkward and clunky and it doesn't help me with all the other elements in (0,1). My instructor said this problem was supposed to be straightforward and I'm afraid that I've already overcomplicated it with so many cases on a.

It seems intuitive that nothing in (0,1) is an accumulation point but I don't know how to construct an epsilon so that for any $$a\in (0,1)$$ that the epsilon neighborhood around this a necessarily has no element in A.

I don't necessarily want a full solution. Some hint as to whether I actually need my cases, or how to go about constructing my epsilon is preferable.

Comment: Is it $E= \frac{n^{(-1)^n}}{n+1}$?

Comment: I was having trouble getting the formatting to work but that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can partition your set E into  $E_{2n}\cup E_{2n+1}$, and then you can see that

$E_{2n}=\frac {n}{n+1}$ , which is strictly increasing, and $E_{2n+1}= \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$, which is strictly decreasing. This means that the limit points of E will be the LUB of $E_{2n}$ and the INF of $E_{2n+1}$ , which are $1$ and $0$ respectively, as you correctly pointed out (the only limit point of a bounded non-decreasing sequence of Reals is its LUB, a.k.a SUP, and the only limit point of a non-increasing sequence of Reals is its GLB a.k.a INF). This means that beyond a certain N, all your terms $E_{2n}$ will be within $e $ of 1, for any $e>0$, and all the odd terms $E_{2n+1}$ will be within $e'>0$ of $0$. This makes any possible third limit point $p$ impossible, as this potential third limit point cannot be approached within less than neither $e< \frac{1-p}{2}$ by points approaching 1, nor can it be approached closer than $e'<\frac{p}{2}$ by the terms approaching $0$, by choosing $N,N'$ large-enough for $E_{2n},E_{2n+1}$ respectively

Comment: We have not discussed accumulation points as limit points, and have not formally introduced the notion of sequence or increasing sequence. Although E can be thought of as a sequence it is formally introduced as a set, and I have few tools other than the epsilon neighborhood classification of accumulation point to use. In that regard I must demonstrate that there is some epsilon neighborhood around every element in (0,1) such that there are no elements of E in this neighborhood.

Comment: Maybe you can show that 1 is an accumulation point of $E_{2n}$ and $0$ is an accumulation point of $E_{2n+1}$ and conclude from the fact that each is monotone, that there cannot be a third limit point.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_n=\frac {2n} {2n+1}$ and $y_n=\frac {\frac {1} {2n+1}} {2n+2}=\frac {1} {(2n+1)(2n+2)}$.  That is, $x_n$ and $y_n$ are $\frac {n^{(-1)^n}} {n+1}$ when we replace $n$ by $2n$ and $2n+1$, respectively.  From there, you can show that $x_n \to 1$ and $y_n \to 0$ and the result follows.

Comment: I can already prove that 0 and 1 are accumulation points, that is not my difficulty. What I cannot do is demonstrate that there are no other accumulation points but these.

Comment: Right.  But this line of reasoning proves that there are no other accumulation points.  If $n$ is even, then your point will be "close" to 1 if $n$ is large and if $n$ is odd, it will be close to $0$.  Thus, there are no other accumulation points.  Of course probably a detail or two you might need to throw in for the writeup, but this is the key observation.

Comment: $$a\in (0,1)$$ is arbitrary, so it is not guaranteed to be close to 0 or 1 regardless of n. I must show that any such a is not an accumulation point.

Comment: I haven't provided all the details (you will need to translate everything into an analysis proof yourself) but the key idea is that if $a \in (0,1)$, then there is some positive distance between $a$ and $0$ and between $a$ and $1$.  So if you are sufficiently close to either $0$ or $1$ for large enough $n$, then you will have to be "far" from $a$.  Try to put this in precise mathematical terms.  It might help to draw a picture first and label the distances and see what's going on before you write the proof up.

Answer (score 0):

It's a different set but the process is the same and $\text{Acc}(\Omega)=\{-1,1\}\neq \text{Acc}(E)=\:\large?$ $$ \large\Omega\normalsize=\left\{\frac{{(-1)^{n}n}}{n+1}\:\colon n\in\mathbb{N} \right\}=\left\{{-1\over 2},{2\over 3},{-3\over 4},{4\over 5},...\right\}.$$

Let's conjecture that $${\large\Omega}^{C}=\underbrace{(-\infty,-1]}_{\mathbb R_{(-1)}}\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N } \left [{-2n-1\over \:\:\:2n+2},{-2n+1\over \:\:\:2n}\right)\large \cup\normalsize (\frac{-1}{\:\:\:2},\frac{1}{2}\:)\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N } \left ({2n-1\over 2n},{2n+1\over 2n+2}\right]\large \cup\normalsize\underbrace{[1,\infty)}_{\mathbb R_{(1)}}.\\ $$

Now, for the closed sets $\:\mathbb R_{(-1)}\&\:\mathbb R_{(1)},\:$we need only to look at the finite bounds to analyse  $\text{Acc}(\Omega)\:$because of the completeness property of $\:\mathbb R.$

In a rigourous fashion we can prove that because $\:\Omega\subset \mathbb Q,\:$ any neighbourhood $\:\mathcal N_{\delta_{>0}}\:$ around $-1\:\&\:1\:$ will be infinite in cardinality.
Therefore $\:(-1 \land 1)\in \text{Acc}(\Omega)\iff\{-1,1\}\subset \text{Acc}(\Omega)$.

Usually to prove that $\:\text{Acc}(\Omega)\subset\{-1,1\}\:$ we use absurdity. That is, we assume an arbitrary element $\:x\in\text{Acc}(\Omega)\:$ that must belong to $\Omega:$  $$\text{Let }\:\hat D=\Large|\normalsize{\frac{{|(-1)^{n+1}|(n+1)}}{n+2}}-\frac{{|(-1)^{n}|n}}{n+1}\Large|\normalsize\ > \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)}:=\hat\delta,\:\forall n\in\mathbb N \\ \text{Thus, }\:\exists\:\hat\delta_{_{>0}} <\hat D\:\:\:\text{s.t}\:\:\:\mathcal N_{\delta_{>0}}(x)\large\cap \normalsize \Omega=\emptyset \iff x\notin \text{Acc}(\Omega),$$

Contradiction.

Also note that $\:\overline \Omega\supset\text{Acc}(\Omega)=\{-1,1\}$